# How to know which font is using an android app?

Tags: android

I should study some apps of different kinds for homework, also want to determine what kind of font are in use.

I try to open the different apk but don't know where to find the setting about the font (or font-family). 
Can't use online imagine font detector, because are imprecise.

Comment: have you checked in assets folder?

Comment: there are a lot of places where the app can get font from. It's impossible to list all of them. Also make sure you have legal rights to reverse-engineer the apps you are trying to.

Answer (score 1):

You could reverse engineer it, which sounds harder than it is for this purpose.
Get a tool like Apktool (https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) and decompile the APK.

If all goes well, you find a folder called `res/font`, which should have the folders for each font used inside of it.

From the app itself it is not possible to find the font used (unless it is a text processing app where you can select the font yourself..)

Comment: I have used this tool with the following command `apktool d "path of the apk file"` and I find the fonts in the `assets/flutter_assets/fonts`